# How do I find a specific word that does not start with hyphen or a dot

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm in Visual Studio and want to search trough my CSS files to match a whole word that does not have a hyphen or dot or whitespace at the beginning or the end

For instance just I want to find the word **table**.

I don't want to get matches for words like
.help-page-table
.table

I tried this expression and other variations. I'm out of my depth.
(?:[^.]|^)(?:[^-]|^)(table)

Comment: No whitespaces around the word ? are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the negative look behind and the negative look ahead for dot or space or hyphen:

This regex would work:

```
(?<!-|\.|\s)table(?!-|\.|\s)
```

- `(?<!-|\.|\s)` - checks no occurrence of hyphen or dot or space before the regex
- `table` - matches the word "table"
- `(?!-|\.|\s)` - checks no occurrence of hyphen or dot or space after the regex

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gwVLHF/1)

Comment: @user1679443, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this pattern: `(?<![\.-])table(?![\.-])`

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/zjHFip/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the word `table` you could write the pattern with negative lookarounds to assert that the not allowed characters are not to the left and the right.

Add word boundaries to prevent partial word matches.

```
(?<![.\s-])\btable\b(?![.\s-])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![.\s-])` Negative lookbehind, assert not a `.` or a whitespace char or `-` to the left
- `\btable\b` Match the word `table` between word boundaries
- `(?![.\s-])` Negative lookahead, assert not a `.` or a whitespace char or `-` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2EZZMy/1).